# Tracking Alias and the Title under Link Properties

Tags: marketing-cloud

hoping someone can answer what the purposes of these attributes are and how do i report on them? Support havent been able to assist so thought i would ask here.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.. are you trying to get names to come up or understand how link tracking works?

Comment: Hi Data_Kid i am trying to understand how the link tracking works as the documentation doesnt say what it actually does and support have not been able to provide any further information.